# Error like this: Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension

Tags: php

When i am trying to use google API in my PHP project it gives error like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google PHP
>   API Client requires the CURL PHP extension' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\googleplus\src\Google_Client.php:21 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\googleplus

I have curl installed in my laptop.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Hello i am getting this error when i try to use google api from php i also have curl installed. what do i do?

Comment: Can you share your code? And have a look whether the cURL extension is enabled

Comment: Show your code and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using window then follow these steps to enable curl in php**

*Step 1. Open below files*

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

*Step 2. Uncomment the following line in your php.ini file by removing the semicolon (;).*

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

After that it will look something like something below-

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

*Step 3. Restart your apache server*

**If you are using Linux operating system**

Open terminal using `ctrl + alt + t`

Run command :- `sudo apt-get install php5-curl  // Note :- according to php version`

Make sure curl is enabled in the php.ini file path `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini,`

Restart apache server :- `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: You have window or linux operating system, check php version then install curl a/c to version

Comment: go to php ini file and uncomment ;extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: I am not able to see Curl extension in phpinfo().

Answer (score 1):

For php7.2 version in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```